# The client sents message to the server and shows error couldn't sent, whats the problem in the program

Tags: sockets

The client program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int sock, s, n, r;
    char  message[256] , receive[1024];
    int msglen, recvlen;
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host port msg...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Obtain address(es) matching host/port */

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* streaming socket */
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0; /* Any protocol */

    s = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }



    /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
     Try each address until we successfully connect(2).
     If socket(2) (or connect(2)) fails, we (close the socket
     and) try the next address. */

    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1)
            continue;

        if (connect(sock, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
            break; /* Success */

        close(sock);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) { /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not connect\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Send remaining command-line arguments as separate
     datagrams, and read responses from server */

    while(1)
    {
        bzero(message, LEN );
        fgets(message, LEN, stdin);
        printf("The server sent: %s\n",message);
        n = send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not send\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        bzero(message, 255);
        n = recv(sock, message, LEN, 0);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not receive\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("The client received: %s\n", message);
        int i = strncmp("Exit", receive, 4);
                        if(i == 0)
                            break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

The server program:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define LEN 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    struct sockaddr_in storage;
    int sock, s,l,a,n;
    char receive[LEN], response[1024];
    int recvlen = strlen(receive);
    pid_t childpid;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* Datagram socket */
    hints.ai_flags = 0; /* For wildcard IP address */
    hints.ai_protocol = 0; /* Any protocol */
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
     Try each address until we successfully bind(2).
     If socket(2) (or bind(2)) fails, we (close the socket
     and) try the next address. */

    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1)
            continue;

        if (bind(sock, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break; /* Success */

        close(sock);
    }

    if (rp == NULL) { /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    l = listen(sock, 5);
    if(l != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error in listening\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    socklen_t str_storage = sizeof(storage);

        a = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&storage, &str_storage);
            if(a < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "the acceptance is not done\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            while(1)
            {
                bzero(receive, LEN);
                n = recv(a, receive, LEN , 0);
                if(n < 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error in reading\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                printf("The client message: %s\n ", receive);
                bzero(receive, LEN);
                fgets(receive, LEN, stdin);

                n = send(a, receive, recvlen, 0);
                if(n < 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error in replying\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                int i = strncmp("Exit", receive, 4);
                if(i == 0)
                    break;

                printf("The server message: %s\n", receive);

            }
close(a);
return 0;

}
```

linux output both sides:

```
$ ./client localhost 5690
deeeksha hey
The server sent: deeeksha hey

Could not send
```

server output:

```
$ ./server 5690
The client message: deeeksha hey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    n = send(sock, message, strlen(message), 0);
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not send\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Your client is executing this block no matter if the `send` was successful or not. It looks like you've forgot to check for `if (n<0)` but instead just had a block without any condition. Likely a case of copy & paste from somewhere else in your code by forgetting to copy the first line.